# Printing messages in console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I created a java application in Eclipse to connect Plant Simulation via Socket. My first step is just sending and receiving messages "Hello" between plant simulation (PS) and my java application. It worked, but I thought it was strange.

Java application is server. PS is the client.

I run "ServerJava" the first time. When I activate "MyClientSocket" in PS, the message "Hallo Plant Simulation" is received in PS. Then I run method "m_sendMessage" in PS to send message "Hallo Java" to ServerJava. It is sent to ServerJava, but it's not printed in the console. If I deactivate "MyClientSocket" to disconnect, it's printed in the console.

How can the message be printed immediately, when I run the method "m_sendMessage" in PS?

My code:

```java
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
     
    
    public class ServerJava {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            ServerSocket listener = null;
            String line = null;
            Socket clientSocket = null;
    
            // ServerSocket with Port 30005
            try {
                listener = new ServerSocket(30005);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
    
            try {
                System.out.println("Server is waiting to accept user...");
                clientSocket = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("Accept a client!");
    
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter os = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    
                while (true) {
                    // Message to the client: Hello Plant Simulation
                    os.write("Hello Plant Simulation");
                    os.flush();
    
                    //Message from client: Hello Java
                    line = is.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
    
                    os.close();
                }
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Sever stopped!");
        }
    }
```

Code for m_sendMessage:

[image: m_sendMessage]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: **Please** indent your code!

Comment: thank Azro. I tried it before i posted this topic, but it didnt work. Sorry @Shmosel

Comment: This anser may help :
https://stackoverflow.com/q/24722681/5204909

Comment: @R Dhaval Thank you, I found another way. My problem is solved :D.

Comment: How can I edit, that my question is solved? @@